# How can I include unittest.dart in my project?

Tags: unit-testing, dart

I'm aware that I can't import it like other core libraries:

```
#import('dart:unittest');
```

I saw in the [unit test article](http://www.dartlang.org/articles/dart-unit-tests/) that they include it:

```
#import('DART_SDK_PATH/lib/unittest/unittest.dart');
```

So I gave this a try with:

```
#import('C:/Users/Phlox/Documents/dart/dart-sdk/lib/unittest/unittest.dart');
```

No luck. I also tried the relative path without luck. I only received the error: 'Cannot find referenced source: C:/Users/Phlox/Documents/dart/dart-sdk/lib/unittest/unittest.dart'. I then came across some threads that mention:

**pubspec.yaml** (added to same folder as your main dart file)

dependencies:

unittest:

sdk: unittest

**installing packages**

pub install --sdkdir="/path/to/dart-sdk"

**importing**

```
#import("package:unittest/unittest.dart");
```

but this was followed by the the news

> It looks like this will only work on platforms with symlinks (i.e. not
>   Windows, by default).

Is there something I haven't tried that might work?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, is this a client side test, or a server side test?  If you are trying to run the test with an associated .html file (client side), then this recent post on the mailing list might be useful:  https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/d/topic/misc/Vo3jWcXisII/discussion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is is a test running directly in the web browser (rather than on the command line), then try importing directly from the hosted source:

```
#import("http://dart.googlecode.com/svn/branches/bleeding_edge/dart/lib/unittest/unittest.dart");
```

Comment: You're correct. It's being run in the browser. I gave your code a try and got a new error: Not a known scheme: http://dart.googlecode.com/svn/branches/bleeding_edge/dart/lib/unittest/unittest.dart. I looked up the function that throws the error. It's from the builtin library: http://try.dartlang.org/s/nWBG Does this mean I can't include URLs?

Comment: Which build are you using?  I just added the above #import to a web-app in build 8948, and it seemed to work fine.  New App > Web App, Add the above import > Add test("foo", () => true); > Run.

Comment: I started a new project and added your code and it worked. Thanks, Chris. Much appreciated :)